# math problem or variable value problem im not sure

Tags: bash, shell-script, math

I am having an issue comparing epoch times. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have been tasked with identifying and actioning files beyond and during certain date ranges.

In this case, it's a cleanup script. It takes a few parameters to do the search and then checks the dates. My dates are like this:

earliest date we can delete a file -> `date -d "-30days" +"%s"`

earliest date we can compress a file -> `date -d "-14days" +"%s"`

get the file last modified time: `stat -c "%y" "/path/to/file"`

get the epoch from that last modified time: `date -d "<from the obtained time from stat>" +"%s"`

The math goes like this:

```
if (( FILE_TIMESTAMP >= EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE ))
then
    delete file;
elif (( FILE_TIMESTAMP >= EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE ))
then
    compress file;
else
    echo "file skipped as it wasnt in teh date ranges";
fi
```

(edit to the above code: I removed the check for <= EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE here)

The first if statement works as expected. The second works halfway - it does identify that the timestamp is greater than the compress date but the check for less than the delete date appears to be returning false as that section of code never gets run.

Am I doing the math wrong or do I have the variables wrong?

Also, I know my posts are crap. I'll delete my account after this so as to lessen the strain on the community.

Some updates:

Looking at my debug log output I see this:

```
[Time: ][Thread: 883837][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:99] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_DATESTAMP -> 2023-05-07 03:20:29.000000000 -0400 [Time: ][Thread: 883837][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:100] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_TIMESTAMP -> 1683444029
```

The file shown is older than 6 months but was not triggered by the >= delete clause. not sure what I'm doing wrong

For @markp-fuso:

```
declare -- FILE_TIMESTAMP="1688178017"
declare -i EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697037095"
declare -i EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698419495"
FILE_TO_PROCESS -> /opt/cws/log/S93206319.log, FILE_DATESTAMP -> 2023-06-30 22:20:17.000000000 -0400 FILE_TIMESTAMP -> 1688178017, EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE -> 1697037095, EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE -> 1698419495
```

In the log output I see this file being skipped, even though it shouldn't have been.

Also, I must apologize - I cannot share the whole script as it is company property =(

More information:

Specific file pulled that ISN'T working:

```
declare -- FILE_TIMESTAMP="1679107439"
declare -i EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697040305"
declare -i EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698422705"
FILE_TO_PROCESS -> /opt/cws/log/S93382366.log, FILE_DATESTAMP -> 2023-03-17 22:43:59.000000000 -0400 FILE_TIMESTAMP -> 1679107439, EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE -> 1697040305, EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE -> 1698422705
file skipped as it wasnt in teh date ranges
```

and

```
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:93] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - processRequestedFile -> enter
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:94] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Provided arguments: /opt/cws/log/S93382366.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:95] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - ERROR_COUNT -> 0
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:96] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_TO_PROCESS -> /opt/cws/log/S93382366.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:97] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_CORE_NAME -> S93382366
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:98] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_CORE_EXT -> log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:99] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_DATESTAMP -> 2023-03-17 22:43:59.000000000 -0400
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:100] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_TIMESTAMP -> 1679107439
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:107] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_CORE_EXT and FILE_CORE_NAME do not match - executing with a file extension
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:139] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - File has extension log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:298] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - RETURN_CODE -> 0
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:299] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - processRequestedFile -> exit
```

A file that appears to have at least hit the delete clause:

Output from the typeset:

```
declare -- FILE_TIMESTAMP="1703308529"
declare -i EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697040305"
declare -i EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698422705"
FILE_TO_PROCESS -> /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log, FILE_DATESTAMP -> 2023-12-23 00:15:29.000000000 -0500 FILE_TIMESTAMP -> 1703308529, EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE -> 1697040305, EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE -> 1698422705
```

Output from the debug log:

```
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:93] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - processRequestedFile -> enter
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:94] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Provided arguments: /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:95] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - ERROR_COUNT -> 0
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:96] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_TO_PROCESS -> /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:97] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_CORE_NAME -> S20504215
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:98] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_CORE_EXT -> log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:99] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_DATESTAMP -> 2023-12-23 00:15:29.000000000 -0500
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:100] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_TIMESTAMP -> 1703308529
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:107] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - FILE_CORE_EXT and FILE_CORE_NAME do not match - executing with a file extension
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:139] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - File has extension log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:143] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - File timestamp is greater than or equal to the delete date. File -> /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log, Timestamp -> 1703308529, EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE -> 1697035331
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:148] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Deleting file /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log as it falls after the earliest delete date range.
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: processRequestedFile:149] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - EXEC: deleteRequestedFile /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:462] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - deleteRequestedFile -> enter
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:463] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Provided arguments: /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:464] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - REMOVABLE_FILE -> /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:465] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - REMOVABLE_FILE_NAME -> S20504215.log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:466] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - REMOVABLE_FILE_PATH -> /opt/cws/log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:470] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Checking if /opt/cws/log exists...
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:516] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Returning to previous directory /opt/cws/log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:520] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - Previous directory: /opt/cws/log, New working directory: /opt/cws/log
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:530] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - RETURN_CODE -> 1
[Time: ][Thread: 8066][Log: debug.log][Level: DEBUG] - [File: deleteRequestedFile:531] [Method: manageFileLifecycle.sh] - deleteRequestedFile -> exit
```

The goal is to delete any file older than 30 days from the current date, compress anything older than 14 days from the current date but not older than 30 days from the current date (these entries would fall under the delete) and anything younger than 14 days is left alone.

Comment: If `file_timestamp >= earliest_delete_date` is false, which must be the case for the shell to move from the `if` condition to the `else` conditions, then by definition `file_timestamp <= earliest_delete_date` (well, technically it's strictly less than, but anyway) so that check is useless and is always true when it is recahed. But it seems to me your conditions are inverted - shouldn't the timestamp of a file that can be deleted be **less than** the `earliest_delete_date`?

Comment: you know. i was going to comment with my thought process here until yours finally clicked. i think you're right, that second check is useless

Comment: basically, what i want is this:

if the file is older than the earliest date we can delete from, delete it
if its NOT older than that date but it IS older than the compress date compress it
if neither skip it

Comment: just before the `if / elif / else` block add `typeset -p file_timestamp earliest_delete_date earliest_compress_date` (this will show us the actual contents of these variables), then run the script for a couple problematic files, then update the question with the output (filenames plus corresponding `typeset -p` output)

Comment: (possibly important) formatting is lost when you place details in a comment block; preference is to update the question with these additional details; also, if you've updated/modified your code then also update the question to show the latest version of your code

Comment: @markp-fuso i was wondering why my formatting didnt work. ill run as requested and update the original question with both the output and the comment info

Comment: "_I know my posts are crap. I'll delete my account after this so as to lessen the strain on the community_" - that would be a shame. The community is made of people, and so you are implicitly part of that community. Ask away

Comment: it's not clear (to me) how the code is functioning for a given set of epoch values (eg, we're not given a clear example of a tuple of epoch values, the (wrong) result generated by code and the (correct) expected result); having said that ... `bash` variable names are case sensitive (eg, `varx`, `VARX`, `varX` ... are different variables) ... your code shows lowercase variable names while the debug and `typeset -p` outputs show uppercase variable names ... this means the code is dealing with 'empty' (lowercase) variables which could explain the (wrong?) results the code is generating

Comment: the code is using uppercase, my example is lowercase because I'm lazy and didn't hit caps lock or shift. =(

that being said, should I be comparing these numbers differently? should it be less than or equal to and not greater than?

Comment: at this point it's not clear (to me) if the *lazy* code includes other errors (besides capitalization of the variable names); also, so far we've been given exactly one set of epoch values and we're told the associated file was `skipped` but the `if / elif / else` code should generate *something* as output (ie, what does `skipped` mean as it refers to the provided code snippet?); also, we're given a snippet of 'debug log output' which doesn't appear to correspond with the `typeset -p` output (are these supposed to be related?)

Comment: for the one set of epoch tuples we've been provided ... `file_timestamp (1688178017) < earliest_delete_date (1697037095) < earliest_compress_date (1698419495)` so the code generates `do nothing` (as expected); for this particular file (epoch tuple) I'm assuming `shouldn't have been (skipped)` means the file should have been deleted and/or compressed (it's not clear from the description which operation(s) should apply) and if that's the case then, yes, there's a problem with the code logic but we'd need a more precise description of what to do with this particular file (compress? delete? both?)

Comment: @markp-fuso i updated the question with additional (hopefully relevant) information

Comment: Regarding `if (( FILE_TIMESTAMP >= EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE ))
then
    delete file;` - do you REALLY want to delete all your most recently modified files, i.e. all those modified after whatever date `EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE` contains?

Comment: Everything older than 30 days from the current date that the script runs, yes, should be deleted. Everything older than 14 days from the current date that the script runs should be archived.

Comment: Regarding `I must apologize - I cannot share the whole script as it is company property` - you're not expected to post your real script, you're expected to create a minimal, complete script that just demonstrates the problem you're asking for help with along with concise, testable sample input and expected output that can reproduce that problem when the script you provide is run on it.

Comment: Regarding `Everything older than 30 days from the current date that the script runs, yes, should be deleted.` - wouldn't that be `if (( FILE_TIMESTAMP < EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE )) then     delete file`, i.e. ```<``` rather than ```>=```?

Comment: if its less than the earliest delete date would that not mean the timestamp is younger than that date?

Comment: The file timestamp, best I can tell from your code snippets, is the epoch seconds for that files last modification date. Epoch seconds are the number of seconds since 00:00 Jan 1 1970. So an older file would have a smaller timestamp than a newer one. Maybe I'm misreading your question - it's pretty long and without a complete script it can't be 100% clear.

Comment: no you're reading it right. so instead of using > I should be using < .. let me try that and I'll report back

Comment: Regarding `I know my posts are crap. I'll delete my account after this so as to lessen the strain on the community.` - if you do that then any help others with similar problems may get from reading this in future and any points awarded to anyone who answers you will be wiped out so you won't be helping the community in any way by deleting your account. It'd be much better for you and everyone else if you just learned how to ask a good question (same rules here as anywhere else in life), see [ask] and look at questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: @EdMorton, deleting their account wouldn't remove the question, though (it'd just be pointless). They could delete the question separately, though, but not after it has an upvoted answer, IIRC.

Comment: fwiw ... *A file that appears to have at least hit the delete clause:* ... but the file's timestamp is 42 days in the future (today = 10 Nov 2023; file timestamp = 22 Dec 2023) so the code should *not* hit the delete clause (ie, the code should do nothing)

Comment: Looks like you got answers posted now but make sure to consider what the timestamp should be for files you compress - should they end up having todays timestamp or the timestamp of the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the question we have the following rules:

- delete any file older than 30 days from the current date
- compress any file older than 14 days from the current date but not older than 30 days from the current date (these entries would fall under the delete)
- any file younger than 14 days is left alone

From the latest update we're given two sets of epoch values:

```
filename: /opt/cws/log/S93382366.log

        FILE_TIMESTAMP="1679107439"      # Fri Mar 17 21:43:59 CDT 2023
  EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697040305"      # Wed Oct 11 11:05:05 CDT 2023
EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698422705"      # Fri Oct 27 11:05:05 CDT 2023

    code result: ISN'T working (assuming this means code generates "file skipped as it wasnt in the date ranges")

expected result: delete file (more than 30 days old; NOTE: compression should have occurred a long time ago)

-----------

filename: /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log

        FILE_TIMESTAMP="1703308529"      # Fri Dec 22 23:15:29 CST 2023
  EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697040305"      # Wed Oct 11 11:05:05 CDT 2023
EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698422705"      # Fri Oct 27 11:05:05 CDT 2023

    code result: delete file

expected result: file skipped as it wasn't in the date ranges (less than 14 days old; actually, file has timestamp that is 42 days in the future when today = Nov 10 2023)
```

Primary issue with the code:

- an 'older' epoch date is actually going to be *less* than a 'newer' epoch date so ...
- the code needs to be testing for epochs that are *less* than a desired threshold

Correcting the current code to implement the 3 desired rules:

```
if (( FILE_TIMESTAMP < EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE ))
then
    echo "delete file"
elif (( FILE_TIMESTAMP < EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE ))
then
    echo "compress file"
else
    echo "file skipped as it wasn't in the date ranges";
fi
```

If we apply this to our 2 sample files/epoch-tuples we get:

```
filename: /opt/cws/log/S93382366.log

        FILE_TIMESTAMP="1679107439"      # Fri Mar 17 21:43:59 CDT 2023
  EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697040305"      # Wed Oct 11 11:05:05 CDT 2023
EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698422705"      # Fri Oct 27 11:05:05 CDT 2023

code result: delete file

-----------

filename: /opt/cws/log/S20504215.log

        FILE_TIMESTAMP="1703308529"      # Fri Dec 22 23:15:29 CST 2023
  EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE="1697040305"      # Wed Oct 11 11:05:05 CDT 2023
EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE="1698422705"      # Fri Oct 27 11:05:05 CDT 2023

code result: file skipped as it wasn't in the date ranges
```

Comment: you are correct, i changed and it works perfectly. yes I'm truly horrible at math

Answer (score 2):

You have your logic reversed. You're treating those *timestamps* as if they were *ages*. Should be:

```
if (( FILE_TIMESTAMP < EARLIEST_DELETE_DATE ))
then
    delete file
elif (( FILE_TIMESTAMP < EARLIEST_COMPRESS_DATE ))
then
    compress file
else
    echo "file skipped as it wasn't in the date ranges"
fi
```

You  could also do it portably with `find`:

```
find -- "$file" -prune -mtime +29 -exec rm -f -- {} + -o \
  -mtime +13 -exec gzip -- {} + -o \
  -exec echo Skipping {} +
```

Note that despite the `--`, that  fails for values of `$file` that start with `-` (or are `(`, `)`, `!`). `gzip` also has a problem with the file called `-` (which it treats as meaning standard input instead; same for GNU `stat`).

`-mtime +29` is true for files whose age rounded down to an integer number of days is strictly greater than 29, so that's files that are 30 days old or older.

With the `find` of  BSDs, both issues/confusions can be addressed by doing:

```
find -f "$file" -prune -mtime +30d -exec rm -f -- {} + -o \
  -mtime +14d -exec gzip -- {} + -o \
  -exec echo Skipping {} +
```

(note the `d` suffix).

While with recent versions of GNU `find`, one can do:

```
find  -files0-from <(printf '%s\0' "$file") -prune \
  ! -newermt '30 days ago' -exec rm -f -- {} + -o \
  ! -newermt '14 days ago' -exec gzip -- {} + -o \
  -printf 'Skipping %p\n'
```

Do **not** user `-delete` in place of `-exec rm -f {} +` as `-delete` implies `-depth` and do not use `-exec ... ';'` in place of `-exec ... +` in the first 2 `-exec`s in those commands as then the success/failure of the command would be used in the `find` logic.

All those commands can take more than one file to process (with BSD `find`, use `-f "$file1" -f "$file2"...`).

Comment: you are correct, i changed and it works perfectly. yes I'm truly horrible at math